# iOS 4.2.1 Mobile Safari won't show poster image

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, html5-video, poster

I've been working on an iPad-specific site that uses HTML5 video and though I've got video playback working, I can't for the life of me get the poster image to appear.  It looks fine on Desktop Safari.  Here's the code:

```
<video src="video/about_the_man.mp4" controls height=360 width=480  poster="video/posters/about_the_man.jpg"></video>
```

I've using this link as a reference (listing 1.2): https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW6

It says that on iOS the poster image will be shown until the user initiates playback, but right now all I'm getting is a black video-sized screen with a big play button in the center.  I've looked at other postings on this top ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062915/how-do-i-disable-auto-poster-image-generation-on-the-video-tag) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874154/ipad-html5-video-element-not-displaying-poster)) but neither solution has worked for me.  The only thing that's a little bit unconventional about the site is that the video element is in an inline lightbox, so initially on pageload it's not visible, but I don't know why that would make a difference.

Comment: No, not yet.  It seems to be largely iOS-version (and phase of the moon) dependent, though, as I haven't been able to replicate it reliably across iPads.  Ah well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I decided to try my code on other iPad's, and it worked fine. The poster image showed up.

After scratching my head for a bit, the solution was to hard reset the iPad and try again. After a reboot, my iPad displayed the poster image as it should.

Maybe it will work for you?

Comment: After hours of research all I needed to do is restart the iPad. ha! my goodness.

Comment: Can confirm exactly same fix worked for me too with a plain <video> element (no js enhancement) in a page with not lightbox. On a iPad2 iOS 4.3.5

Comment: Still the same on iOS 7.2.1

Answer (score 2):

I found there is a limit to the amount of images you can load on an iPad

Here is what it says:

> I hit a mobile Safari limitation recently when building an AJAX-y site
>   on the iPad. If you load a ton of images eventually mobile Safari cuts
>   you off and will display a [?] instead of the image. After doing some
>   tests it appears that this limit is around 6.5 MB. Here’s a test page
>   I made that attempts to load 20 500kb images. When opening this page
>   on an iPad, 7 of the images don’t appear, even though in Charles they
>   are returning 200 – success. I’m assuming this is similar to the way
>   autoplay is disabled for the video tag on iPad/iPhone. Apple probably
>   wants to make sure users don’t get overloaded with downloads when
>   browsing on 3G.

Anyhow, 6.5 MB is a hefty load and wouldn’t fare well on 3G, but for one reason or another you may want to work around this limitation. I found the easiest way to patch my code was to load the image into a canvas tag using `drawImage()`. The canvas tag appears to be immune to the limitation.

Here’s [another test page](http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2010/05/05/ipad-safari-image-limit-workaround/) using the canvas tag, all the images should load.